# Call non static methods from another class

Tags: java, static

I'm have 2 classes. `Car` and `Attendant`.

```
public Attendant(int staffNum, String id, boolean available, attNm name, Cars assign) {
    this.staffNum = staffNum;
    this.id = id;
    this.available = available;
    this.name = name;
    this.assign = assign;
}

public Cars(String carID, String plateNum, String position, Attendant assignedTo, long currTime) {
    this.carID = carID;
    this.plateNum = plateNum;
    Cars.position = position;
    Cars.assignedTo = assignedTo;
    this.currTime = currTime;
}
```

My attandants are created with a for loop:

```
createIDList();
int staffAmount = getStaffAmount();

for (int x = 0; x < staffAmount; x++) {
    Attendant att = new Attendant(x + 1, Attendant.tempArray[x], true, attNm.getNm(), null);
    myAtt.add(att);
}
for (int x = 0; x < myAtt.size(); x++) {
    System.out.println(myAtt.get(x));
}
```

All parameters are from a function which gets them from an `ArrayList`. All the attendants have the same name.

It is the same with cars.
Each time I create a car, it's from a function and the cars will have their name: car

When they are created my attendants and my cars are added in their `ArrayList` (ArraylistCar and arraylistAtt)

But when I'm creating new cars all cars are outputted with the same IDs and the attendants details are wrongly outputted.

Someone told me that static methods and variables are the reasons of this problem. So I tried to remove some statics but I get errors. 
If I remove static with the getID method I can't call it in the attendant class.
And these cases happen also when I'm creating a new class with methods as parameters(the methods are no longer static so I can't called them from the other class).

Please help me I'm stuck. I know its very long I try different methods but nothing worked.
I also put my `toString()` methods in case it's a problem with them.
Some people told me also to put my whole code and my output, so its completely below if you need it.

car:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Car:" + plateNum + " ID:" + carID + " Position:" + position + " Assigned to:" + assignedTo.getId() 
    + "(" + assignedTo.getName() + ")" + " Parked at:" + convert(currTime);
}
```

Attandant:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Attendant [staffNum=" + staffNum + ", id=" + id + ", available=" + available + ", name=" + name
            + ", Car=" + assign + "]";
}
```

PS:English is not my native language.

My whole code is here:

```
public class Cars {

    private static String carID;
    private String plateNum;
    private static String position;
    private static Attendant assignedTo;
    private long currTime;
    static ArrayList<String> tempArray2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Cars(String carID, String plateNum, String position, Attendant assignedTo, long currTime) {
        this.carID = carID;
        this.plateNum = plateNum;
        Cars.position = position;
        Cars.assignedTo = assignedTo;
        this.currTime = currTime;
    }

    private static void createCarsID() {
        for (int x = 0; x < Garage.getCarsCapacity(); x++) {
            String tempCarID = ("CR" + (x + 1));
            tempArray2.add(tempCarID);
        }
    }

    public static String getID() {
        createCarsID();
        String tempID = null;
        String tempPos = null;
        for (int x = 0; x < Garage.getCarsCapacity(); x++) {
            if (tempArray2.get(x) != null) {
                tempID = tempArray2.get(x);
                tempPos = tempArray2.get(x);
                tempArray2.remove(tempArray2.get(x));
                getPos(tempPos);
                //tempArray2.get(x) = null;
                break;
            }
        }
        return tempID;
    }

    public static void getPos(String IdToPos) {
        String strPos = IdToPos.substring(2);
        int pos = Integer.parseInt(strPos);
        position = "GR" + pos;
    }

    public String getPlateNum() {
        return plateNum;
    }

    public static String getCarID() {
        return carID;
    }

    public static String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public long getCurrTime() {
        return currTime;
    }
    public static Attendant getAssignedTo() {
        return assignedTo;
    }

    public static String askCarID() {
        boolean valid = false;
        System.out.println("Please enter your car's plate number.");
        Scanner scanCarID = new Scanner(System.in);
        String scannedCarID = scanCarID.nextLine();
        while (!valid) {
            if (scannedCarID.matches("^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9]$")) {
                valid = true;
                System.out.println(scannedCarID);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid plate number. Ex: AF 378");
                askCarID();
            }
        }
        return scannedCarID.toUpperCase();
    }

    public String convert(long miliSeconds) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car:" + plateNum + " ID:" + carID + " Position:" + position + " Assigned to:" + assignedTo.getId() 
        + "(" + assignedTo.getName() + ")" + " Parked at:" + convert(currTime);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Attendant {

    private static int staffAmount = 10;

    public int staffNum;
    private String id;
    private boolean available;
    private attNm name;
    private Cars assign;

    private String user;
    static String[] tempArray = new String[staffAmount];
    static ArrayList<Attendant> myAtt = new ArrayList<Attendant>();

    public Attendant(int staffNum, String id, boolean available, attNm name, Cars assign) {
        this.staffNum = staffNum;
        this.id = id;
        this.available = available;
        this.name = name;
        this.assign = assign;
    }

    public Attendant(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public static void createAtt() {
        createIDList();
        int staffAmount = getStaffAmount();

        Attendant att = null;
        for (int x = 0; x < staffAmount; x++) {
            att = new Attendant(x + 1, Attendant.tempArray[x], true, attNm.getNm(), null);
            myAtt.add(att);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < myAtt.size(); x++) {
            System.out.println(myAtt.get(x));
        }
    }

    public static void startWork() {
        createAtt();
    }

    public static Attendant askForAtt() {
        Scanner scanAtt = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random randAtt = new Random();
        //Attendant  asnAtt = null;
        System.out.println("Do you require an Attendant ? Y or N");
        String response = scanAtt.next();
        if ((response.equals("y")) || (response.equals("yes")) || (response.equals("Yes")) || (response.equals("Y"))) {
            // Cars.setAssignedTo(myAtt.get(randAtt.nextInt(myAtt.size())));
            Attendant attendant = myAtt.get(randAtt.nextInt(myAtt.size()));
            while(!attendant.isAvailable()){
                attendant = myAtt.get(randAtt.nextInt(myAtt.size()));
            }
            return attendant;

        } else if ((response.equals("n")) || (response.equals("no")) || (response.equals("No")) || (response.equals("N"))) {
            return new Attendant ("User");
        }
        return new Attendant ("User");    //If input is neither Yes nor No then return new Attendant    
    }

    public static void assignCarAtt(){

    }

    public int getStaffNum() {
        return staffNum;
    }

    public static int getStaffAmount() {
        return staffAmount;
    }

    public void setStaffNum(int staffNum) {
        this.staffNum = staffNum;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        this.available = available;
    }

    public boolean getAvailable(){
        return available;
    }

    public void setAssign(Cars assign) {
        this.assign = assign;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return available;
    }

    public attNm getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void createIDList() {
        for (int x = 0; x < staffAmount; x++) {
            tempArray[x] = ("Att" + (x + 1));
        }
    }

    public String strAssignAttCar(Cars assign){
        String result = null;
        if(assign!=null){
            result = Cars.getCarID();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Attendant [staffNum=" + staffNum + ", id=" + id + ", available=" + available + ", name=" + name
                + ", Car=" + assign + "]";
    }

}
```

Garage class printing;

```
  Car:HU 457 ID:CR2 Position:GR2 Assigned to:Att10(Ava) Parked at:18:32:08, Car:HU 457 ID:CR2 Position:GR2 Assigned to:Att9(Elizabeth) Parked at:18:32:21]
   // Should have been like that:
    Car:HU 457 ID:CR1 Position:GR1 Assigned to:Att10(Ava) Parked at:18:32:08, Car:HU 457 ID:CR2 Position:GR2 Assigned to:Att9(Elizabeth) Parked at:18:32:21]
```

Attendant class printing;

```
    Attendant [staffNum=9, id=Att9, available=false, name=Elizabeth, Car=Car:HU 457 ID:CR2 Position:GR2 Assigned to:Att9(Elizabeth) Parked at:18:32:21]
    Attendant [staffNum=10, id=Att10, available=false, name=Ava, Car=Car:HU 457 ID:CR2 Position:GR2 Assigned to:Att10(Ava) Parked at:18:32:08]
   // Should have been like that:
    Attendant [staffNum=9, id=Att9, available=false, name=Elizabeth, Car=Car:HU 457 ID:CR2 Position:GR2 Assigned to:Att9(Elizabeth) Parked at:18:32:21]
    Attendant [staffNum=10, id=Att10, available=false, name=Ava, Car=Car:HU 457 ID:CR1 Position:GR1 Assigned to:Att10(Ava) Parked at:18:32:08]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it makes more sense to make the `Cars` class singular, ie `Car`.

Background info: in the statement `Cars car1 = new Cars()`, `Cars` is the class, and `car1` is an instance of the `Cars` class. This issue is caused by confusing two.

A static variable/method is not associated with any particular instance of the class; it is only associated with the class. So, when you declare `carID` as `static`, you are saying that there will only be one global `Cars.carID`, rather than many `car1.carID`, `car2.carID`, etc. Make sure that instance variables/methods are not static.

The problem you are getting when you remove the `static` keyword is because you are calling `Cars.getCarID()` instead of `car1.getCarID()`. You need to change all method calls on the class to method calls on an instance of the class.

tl;dr: To fix this issue, remove all `static` keywords and change all static references to methods like `Cars.getCarID()` to `car1.getCarID()`.

Example of object oriented programming (note there are no static methods or variables, except the main method):

Car.java:

```
class Car {
    int id;
    int speed;

    Car(int id, int speed) {
        this.id = id;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    void setSpeed(int newSpeed) {
        speed = newSpeed;
    }

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    void goFast() {
        System.out.println("VROOM! This car is going so fast: " + speed);
    }
}
```

Person.java:

```
class Person {
    Car myCar;
    int id;

    Person(int id, Car car) {
        this.id = id;
        this.myCar = car;
    }

    int getCar() {
        return myCar;
    }

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    void floorIt() {
        myCar.setSpeed(myCar.getSpeed() + 10);

    void drive() {
        myCar.goFast();
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car ferrari = new Car(1, 1000);
        Car bmw = new Car(2, 500);

        Person alice = new Person(1, ferrari);
        Person bobby = new Person(2, bmw);

        alice.drive();
        bobby.drive();

        bobby.floorIt();
        bobby.drive();

    }
}
```

Comment: When I do something like that: Cars car1 = new Cars(car1.getID(), car1.askCarID().......); It's telling me the local variable car1 may have not be initialised

Comment: Any more suggestion plz?

Comment: @Kavi, you can't call methods on car1 in its constructor. It doesn't exist yet, so it doesn't have an id

Comment: So what can i do to call them. I can't put them static.

Comment: @Kavi you need to create instances of Car first, using variables or constants in the constructor. I'll edit my response my an example

Comment: Thanks for help. So does mean it I should change the constructor to only car() with no parameters. Then I create one and use the methods. In this case I can I make this object to contain details like his ID, position or the time parked, things like that.